# How can I modify xml file using java without disabling load-external-dtd feature?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to change my configuration file of hibernate on run time. So, trying to modify the xml using `DocumentBuilderFactory` for parsing and setting the feature as `docFactory=setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false)`
But, after setting it to false, hibernate dtd is getting removed on runtime which throws "grammar not found" exception. And, without disabling above feature, I can't modify my xml. Please help.